# Print out only headers in Rails request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know how to access a header in Rails

```
request.headers["HEADER_NAME"]
```

However, I want to get all headers passed by a browser. I see that I can enumerate it

```
request.headers.each { |header| ... }
```

However, this will spit out both headers and other environment variables. Is there a way to get only headers?

**Update 1**

My problem isn't interation. My problem is distinguising between environment variables and headers. Both of them will be reported while interation using each or keys.

Comment: the current list of answers all seems to mis-understood the question.. I've also encountered similar need, and don't exactly know how to solve it yet..

Comment: In express.js you get whole request as an object. Is there similar in Ruby on rails ?

Comment: @songyy I seemed to find a solution - pls check out my answer if still needed

Answer (score 32):

**Solution**

By convention, headers do not usually contain dots. Nginx even [rejected](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,44453) requests with dots in headers by default. So I think it's quite a safe assumption to go with.

On contrary, all rails environment garbage is namespaced e.g. `action_dispatch.show_exceptions`, `rack.input` etc.

These two facts conveniently suggest a way to distinguish external headers from internal variables:

```
request.headers.env.reject { |key| key.to_s.include?('.') }
```

Works neat.

---

**Benchmarking a bit**

Note, that `include?('.')` implementation works about 4 times faster than matching `=~ /\./`

```
Benchmark.measure { 500000.times { hsh.reject { |key| key.to_s =~ /\./ } } }
 => real=2.09
Benchmark.measure { 500000.times { hsh.reject { |key| key.to_s.include?('.') } } }
 => real=0.58
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 17):

By using

```
request.headers.each { |key, value|  }
```

This is iterating your requested header with (key+value), but if you want specific values you have to use key name like, HTTP_KEYNAME because whenever HTTP request come it will append HTTP to keys and be sure about uppercase because it is case sensitive.

**for example:**

if we have passed **auth_token** as header request parameter and want to access, we can use this.

```
request.headers["HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN"]
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try this to get only headers list from request

```
request.headers.first(50).to_h.keys
```

It will convert request.headers object into array and then to hash to get list of all keys in request to be used as

```
request.headers["keyname"]
```

It might be not much efficient but I think it can do the job.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

not sure if this is any helpful but I ended up using this brute force approach

```
request.env.select {|k,v|
  k.match("^HTTP.*|^CONTENT.*|^REMOTE.*|^REQUEST.*|^AUTHORIZATION.*|^SCRIPT.*|^SERVER.*")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want headers:

```ruby
request.headers.to_h.select { |k,v|
  ['HTTP','CONTENT','AUTHORIZATION'].any? { |s| k.to_s.starts_with? s }
}
```

If you want everything that's not an env var:

```ruby
request.headers.to_h.select { |k,v|
  ['HTTP','CONTENT','REMOTE','REQUEST','AUTHORIZATION','SCRIPT','SERVER'].any? { |s|
    k.to_s.starts_with? s
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be probably looking for :

```
request.env
```

This will basically create a Ruby Hash of the whole request object.

For more details, check this question:
[How do I see the whole HTTP request in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850256/how-do-i-see-the-whole-http-request-in-rails)

Comment: Output would be too long to scan through. a more selective approach is needed.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do

```
request.headers.each { |key, value|  }
```

In general when iterating over a hash ruby looks at the arity of your block and gives you either a pair (key + value) or separate variables. (The hash in this case is an object internal to the headers object)

Comment: My problem isn't interation. My problem is distinguising between environment variables and headers. Both of them will be reported while interation using each or keys.

Comment: request.headers doesn't respond to a keys method. It's an instance of ActionDispatch::Http::Headers